# eu estou tentando fazer quando o usuario clicar em um link do meu site adicionar uma class chamada ativo e quando ele clicar de novo remove essa class

Tags: javascript-eventos

```
// esse é o codigo javascript
const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]'));

links.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", adiciona);
});

function adiciona(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  tira();
  this.classList.add("ativo");
}

function tira() {
  links.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove("ativo");
  });
}
```

Comment: Basicamente eu queria que quando eu clicasse em um link ele removesse o ativo dos outros e deixasse so no que eu cliquei e quando eu clicasse dnv sobre o mesmo link ele removesse o ativo desse que ja existe

Answer (score 0):

Fiz umas alterações na sua função `adiciona`, creio que vá resolver seu problema.

```js
// esse é o codigo javascript
const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]'));

links.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", adiciona);
});

function adiciona(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const current = document.querySelector('a[href^="#"].ativo');
  tira();
  if (current !== e.currentTarget) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.add("ativo");
  }
}

function tira() {
  links.forEach((item) => {
    item.classList.remove("ativo");
  });
}
```